# Можно ли близко к сердцу... воспринимать?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> И точно знаешь – там, в темноте зрительного зала, человек четыреста
>   сидят, специально пришли, и все на тебя смотрят, и каждое слово твоё
>   ловят, и совершенно непонятно почему всю эту бутафорию так серьёзно к
>   сердцу воспринимают.

Если *можно* не править, *нужно* не править, просто мне непривычно...

Comment: Если это авторская находка, оживляющая скуку остального повествования (только он может сознаться), типа "вот где собака порылась", то непривычность не имеет роли и не влияет значения :) , а так - из конструкции "близко к сердцу" попросту выпал грамматический противовес, хоть принимай, хоть воспринимай бутафорию. Не знаю, что можно делать "серьёзно к сердцу".

Comment: Меня не серьёзность смутила! А - принимать/воспринимать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить Л.Н.Толстому, то *близко к сердцу **не только можно**, но и **нужно** воспринимать:*

**Люди , которые воспринимают все пустяки близко к сердцу - больше всех способны искренне любить.**
[**Л.Н.Толстой**](https://tetatet-club.ru/Aphorism890_lev_nikolaevich_tolstoi.htm)

*И я такой человек, который все это **воспринимает близко к сердцу.***
[**Чувствующий**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=Y6xkCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D1%83&source=bl&ots=7CjTZIJl9z&sig=BQ0OOU439jQrtvz-rKy4A4gfThs&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOsY3u5MDTAhXIfywKHUYAA-A4ChDoAQhOMAc#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D1%83&f=false)

Из интернета:
 *Как перестать **воспринимать** мелочи **близко к сердцу***?
*И, главное, не стоит **воспринимать** критику слишком **близко к сердцу.***

*Тогда перед нами открывается великая творческая мистерия мира, и мы можем **воспринимать ее и сердцем,** и взором, и разумом.*
[**Поющее сердце**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=_l0DCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D1%83&source=bl&ots=HBMgz3j-yt&sig=a2qTTCqKRIxkcJ7fCk8EFGuKHVE&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRnva81MDTAhXCE5oKHTUPCxQ4KBDoAQhdMAk#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D1%83&f=false)

*Выходит, что можно воспринимать и сердцем, и близко к сердцу.*

Comment: Есть разница между "близко к сердцу воспринимают" и "серьёзно к сердцу воспринимают" : первое - устойчивое выражение, второе - его авторская переработка, не совсем удачная на мой взгляд. Также есть разница между "воспринимать сердцем" и "воспринимать к сердцу", второе не кажется мне удачным.

Comment: Да, конечно, разница есть - в обоих случаях. Но автор вопроса спрашивал категорически: "Можно ли близко к сердцу… воспринимать?" (смотрите комментарии). Я в ответе и так привела два варианта, но без обсуждения "серьёзно" - так, как спрашивала Галина.

Comment: Вы правы, в заголовке вопроса - "близко к сердцу воспринимать" а в "теле" вопроса - "серьёзно к сердцу воспринимают". Это вносит путаницу.

Comment: Я порассуждала - о серьёзности воспринимания к сердцу - "для себя". Но после участия в обсуждении на МЕТЕ - "Каким должен быть хороший ответ на заданный вопрос?" - решила, что полемика вокруг "серьёзно" будет не по теме.